# Magento 2 : Add condition for form element in email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, contact-form

Added new input field in default Contact form :

> /magento_root/app/design/frontend/VENDER_NAME/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

```
<input title="Test Id" name="testid" id="testid" value=""/>
```

Created new custom template and assigned it to Contact Form with below code.

```
{{trans "Test Id: %testid" testid=$data.testid}}
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

I tried to add condition like :

```
{{depend $data.testid}}
  {{trans "Test Id: %testid" testid=$data.testid}}
{{/depend}}
```

But this is not working.

If $data.testid is empty then I don't want to print that line :

```
{{trans "Test Id: %testid" testid=$data.testid}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way found to add condition explained in question, 
I did it using following way:

Created 2 different email templates and then I am going to assign a template depending on condition.

Inside controller, I am checking that if $testid is not empty then I am assigning a email template with

```
{{trans "Test Id: %testid" testid=$data.testid}}
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```

otherwise  I am assigning another which is,

```
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
```